# logback in spring-OSGI with pax-runner

Tags: osgi, logback, pax-runner

We are running **OSGI** bundles with pax-runner. We are logging using logback over slf4j.

The problem is **logback** tries to look for logback.xml in classpath, but in **pax-runner** where should I place logback.xml so that pax-runner configure logback accordingly?

I have tried with JoranConfigurator to load logback.xml which is included in bundle classpath, but it assumes classpath as the container in which the bundle is running (in my case it is runner folder where all the bundle jars are placed).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual approach would be to create a fragment bundle that is attached to the logback bundle and put logback.xml in there. Fragment bundles "extend" other bundles, so their contents are available to the classloader of the host bundle. This way, logback can find logback.xml in the classpath.

Comment: Thanks Kork. Your solution helped. :)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to configure logback to read the configuration
file from outside the classpath.

This can be done by setting VM options `-Dlogback.configurationFile=/dir/conf/logback.xml`

Comment: Hi Epi, Basically I do not have any specific path for logback.xml since it is bundled. So I have followed Kork's solution.