# Logback include fragment in OSGi container

Tags: java, osgi, logback, equinox, pax-runner

I have a project `a-conf` with `src/main/resources/logback/conf/a/CommonAppenders.xml` file:

```
<included>
    <appender name="FILE" class="FileAppender" />
</included>
```

Also i have another project `a-runable` with `logback.xml` config which imports `CommonAppenders.xml`:

```
<configuration>
    <!-- this is classpath import -->
    <include resource="logback/conf/a/CommonAppenders.xml" />
    ...
</configuration>
```

I can compile `a-runable` in standalone jar with all dependencies (`a-conf` is one of them) included or as an OSGi bundle. When i run standalone app everything is ok - log files appears as specified in `CommonAppenders.xml`. But when i run OSGi container no log files are created. I think logback just cannot include resource from classpath because every bundle in OSGi container has its own classloaders (logback uses `ClassLoader.getResource()` to include file).

I've checked `Export-Package: logback.conf.a` in `a-conf.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` (this is done by maven bundlor plug-in) - it is ok. Added `Import-Package: logback.conf.a` to `a-runable` with no effect.

I have no ideas what can i do (no code to change, just configs). Any help would be welcome.

P.S. I've found similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031731/logback-in-spring-osgi-with-pax-runner), but `logback.xml` is already in classpath and its own appenders works fine. Also i do not have any `FileNotFoundException`s in existing logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, I believe Logback's startup errors are simply dropped if you don't configure a listener (but I may be remembering wrong). The key is likely that a-conf needs to be a Fragment of the bundle that contains logback.jar. That's what I've done for my bundle that has some homebrew appenders.

If you want to see a setup where Logback is pre-configured to output its startup errors to the OSGi container, take a look at Pax-Logger 1.7 - https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.logging/tree/master/pax-logging-logback

Comment: Thanks a lot! Making a-conf a fragment of a-runnable really helped!